# author indexing with natbib and imakeidx

Tags: natbib, imakeidx, makeindex

I'm hoping to produce an index of cited authors. I'm using `imakeidx` and `natbib` and calling `\citeindextrue` in the document, but the citations simply do not seem to register in the resulting .idx file (keywords entered manually do get indexed).

Following is a minimal example, which outputs a bibliography and index with two entries only ('key', and 'word').

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{anc.bib}
@Book{Frede1987,
  Title                    = {Essays in Ancient Philosophy},
  Author                   = {Michael Frede},
  Publisher                = {University of Minnesota Press},
  Year                     = {1987}
}
@InCollection{Frede1990,
  Title                    = {An Empiricist View of Knowledge: Memorism},
  Author                   = {Michael Frede},
  Booktitle                = {Companions to Ancient Thought 1: Epistemology},
  Publisher                = {Cambridge University Press},
  Year                     = {1990},
  Editor                   = {Stephen Everson},
  Pages                    = {225-250}
}
@Book{Lorenz2006,
  Title                    = {The Brute Within},
  Author                   = {Hendrik Lorenz},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\citeindextrue

Some citations: \citet[243--60]{Frede1987} and \citet[227--34]{Frede1990} and also \citet[4--7]{Lorenz2006}. Some keywords: \index{key} key, \index{word} word.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{anc}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

What I am hoping to produce is an index that includes 'key', 'word', and also the page numbers and author names for each cited author. I've tried `makeidx`: same result.